# In my rails app why does an instance variable initialized in a before filter only work for one action and not the other actions in the list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby class that reads a csv file and populates a hash and returns the data via a method called 
`present_data_sample()`. I initialize the instance of this class in a before filter with the `only:` option so that it only initializes for 2 actions `before_action :initialize_processor, only: [:import :index]`. But this only seems to be working for the `import` action not the index.

Below is the controller and the index.html.erb page.

```
class FileProcessorController < ApplicationController
    before_action :initialize_processor, only: [:import, :index]

    def index
        #@index_name=@file_processor.load_index()
        @second_sample = @file_processor.present_data_sample()
    end

    def upload
    end

    def import
        @file_sample = @file_processor.present_data_sample()
        if (@file_sample) then
            render 'index'
        else
            render 'index' #no data? no problem, still render..
        end

    end

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def initialize_processor
        file_path = params[:file].path
        @file_processor = FileProcessorService.new(file_path)

    end
end
```

Below is the view in which I should see both data from the import action as well as the index action. The `@file_processor` should have been initialized for both actions according to my understanding... I have other methods in `@file_processor` that I would like to use.

```
<h1>FileProcessor#index</h1>
<p>File Data Below:</p>

  <h2> First File Content: </h2>
  <%=@file_sample%>

 <h2> Same content again from index action: </h2>
  <%=@second_sample%>
```

And here is the view that actually triggers the `import` action.

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Upload File</h1>
    <%= form_tag(import_path, multipart: true) do %>
        <%= file_field_tag(:file) %>
        <%= submit_tag("import") %>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

Could someone please advise why the second set of data is not there? I must be missing some fundamental concept. If you could clarify, that would be awesome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Rendering the `index` **view** does not trigger the `index` **method** of your controller. When you call the `import` action, your `@file_processor` variable is set, but the `index` method is not called, so the `@second_sample` variable is not set.

FileProcessController describes a class. All of the methods you've defined are **instance** methods. `@whatever` is an **instance** variable of a given instance of a controller class. So when you get a request that matches `FileProcessController` and the `import` action, Rails creates an instance of this class and calls the `import` method on this instance (it does not call `import` on the class). That `import` method can call other instance methods, set instance variables, whatever, on itself (not the class). Then at some point (normally) `render` is called, which typically renders a view template, and that template has access to those instance variables (e.g., `@whatever`). There is a different instance of the class for each request - these instances cannot access each others' instance variables.

You can accomplish what you say you wanted simply setting `@second_sample` in your `initialize_processor` method. As I mentioned, however, I think the example below (without using the `before_action` filter) is a little clearer to read and accomplishes the same thing, in my opinion.

That said, I'm probably missing your intent here because it's hard for me to imagine why you would have the index action show your index view with both samples (whatever those are), and then have the import action render the same index view with the same information.

```
class FileProcessorController < ApplicationController

  def index
    initialize_processor
    #if you don't call render, Rails will try to render a view template
    #that matches the action name. As a result, this method is doing exactly
    #the same thing as your import method. That's why I think it's unlikely
    #that you really want to do what this code actually does.
  end

  def upload
  end

  def import
    initialize_processor
    render 'index'
  end

  private

    def initialize_processor
      file_path = params[:file].path
      @file_processor = FileProcessorService.new(file_path)
      @second_sample = @file_processor.present_data_sample()
    end
end
```

Comment: I would just also add that there isn't really a need to use a before filter here. You might find the code more readable if you just called the `initialize_processor` method in the `index` and `import` methods directly, so when you read the code for that method, you see what it is doing, instead of winding your way through the criteria on the filter.

Comment: can I call the initialize_processor method in other methods of the controller? Do I need to use the keyword `self`? I'm reading up on self. Why would I need to use that here??

Comment: This is just a ruby class, and these are all instance methods defined for that class. Any of your methods can call any of your other methods. The only thing I suppose you should keep in mind is that once you call `render` somewhere, whatever you do after that isn't going to change what is available to the view. You don't need to use `self`. If you'd like I can edit the answer to illustrate what I was describing above.

Comment: But the controller from what I've been studying is not really a ruby class though right? Since if I declare a variable `@somevar = 2`, that variable can't be used in other controller actions. Where as in a ruby class you can share that amongst methods of the class. Could you alter your answer above as you mentioned? it would be a great help if you can demystify this for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits the form the import action is called. That means only the `import` action of the `FileProcessorController` is executed. In your example, only the `@file_sample` variable will be populated because the `import` method does not populates the `@second_sample` variable.

Comment: I already know its not populating the @second_sample. My question is Why is it not doing that??